# Is this a good Complex Value Type candidate in modelling?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For instance, I want to represent the 'weight' of a product. A weight has to be specified by two things, a value and a unit, i.e. 75kg. So:

```
create(p:Prduct {name:"iphone"})-[r:weight]->(w:Weight {value:300, unit:'g'})
```

or create two relationships from the Weight node.

Is this a sensible approach to model typical quantities with units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the queries you will run in your database. But seems to me that if all your `:Weight` nodes of your database are related to only one `:Product` node, then maybe you should put these properties into the product nodes. That is:

```
(:Product {name:"iphone", weight_value:300, weight_unit:'g'})
```

instead of:

```
(:Product {name:"iphone"})-[r:weight]->(:Weight {value:300, unit:'g'})
```

Using all properties in the product node has the advantage that you don't need to transverse the `:wheight` relationship when filtering by unit weight.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that, the number of product's properties will increase significantly, since there are quite lot of complex properties like 'weight'. Another one is how to perform a search: 'What's the weight of iPhone?' If I have a relationship Weight leading to a Weight node, I can simply return the Weight node. Otherwise, I need to return individual attributes of Product node.

Comment: @user697911 Yes, I understand your point of view. But it seems to me that is a mistake to use nodes as a simple repository of related properties. Also, you can specify the related properties you want when querying (eg `MATCH (p:Product {name:"iphone"}) RETURN {weight_value : p.weight_value, weight_unit:p.weight_unit}`).  Although you have the "cost" of specifying all the properties you need, it's cheaper than an extra jump to a `:Weight` node considering performance.

Comment: That makes sense. A practical problem would look like this: a product has an attribute like "SupportedVideoFormat: RM/RMVB、WMV、H.264、MPEG1/2、MPEG4、DIVX、XVD、AVS". In order to make the unstructured string value structured, SupportedVideoFormat would become an independent node with the 8 specific format as attributevalues. Otherwise, I have to create individual properties directly on the original product node.

Comment: @user697911 but you can use `SupportedVideoFormat` as an array of strings. Then save the desired supported video formats as items of the array. `node.SupportedVideoFormat = ['RM/RMVB', 'WMV', 'H.264']` or `node.SupportedVideoFormat = ['RM/RMVB', 'WMV']`

Comment: Then what's the syntax for the "create" statement? I didn't find the documentation.

Comment: To create a node with property of type list? create `(n:Node {SupportedVideoFormat : ['RM/RMVB', 'WMV']})`